# clase con constructor que se le proporciona un diccionario

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Estoy intentando hacer este problema pero es que no consigo verlo para escribirlo:

> Realiza una clase a cuyo constructor se le proporcionará un diccionario y crea un método que pueda recorrer dicho diccionario con Selenium, mostrar keys, recuperar valores, buscar un valor al azar y abrirla en el navegador con el plugin de selenium.

Sinceramente no se ni por dónde cogerlo. Espero me podáis ayudar.

PD: un ejemplo de diccionario: *(también tengo la duda de como se haría si hubiera dentro del mismo diccionario mas deportistas en otro apartado)*

```
futbolistas = {
    1 : "Casillas", 15 : "Ramos",
    3 : "Pique", 5 : "Puyol",
    11 : "Capdevila", 14 : "Xabi Alonso",
    16 : "Busquets", 8 : "Xavi Hernandez",
    18 : "Pedrito", 6 : "Iniesta",
    7 : "Villa"
}
```

Un saludo y gracias.

Comment: Creas un clase con los métodos que te piden, dichos métodos usa un diccionario y en `__init__` define el atributo que corresponde al diccionario. No se cuál es la pregunta aquí, las instrucciones son muy claras. Te recomiendo que solo formules preguntas cuando tengas un error en especifico.

Comment: mi duda es básicamente que no se como estructurarlo ni plantearlo. He hecho esto y dudo que sea correcto:
class Prueba():
    def __init__(self):
        self.dicc = {}

Comment: `class Prueba(): def __init__(self,dicc): self.dicc = dicc `. Esta sentencia define la clase en cuestión y el método `__init__`, este método se inicializa apenas se inicializa la clase, solicita un argumento y lo define como atributo de la clase. Entonces cuando se intente inicialzar la clase creando un objeto se deberá de incluir un diccionario como argumento, este argumento va aser un atributo global de clase, por lo tanto se podrá usar en los métodos.

Comment: Cuando adjuntes código y tengas una duda puntual, con mucho gusto te daría una explicación más elaborada.

Comment: La faena es que no es una duda puntual. No se plantear la sintaxis y como hacerlo. Si supiera escribirlo, aunque mal te lo mandaría encantado. Pero no soy capaz. (como has podido comprobar ni siquiera era capaz de crear una clase y a un constructor asignarle un diccionario, como para saber hacer  el resto...)

Comment: No tienes conocimientos de POO en Python?

Comment: No... soy tester funcional y he creado algunos test automatizados para dar el salto a la automatización. Pero me está resultando complicado porque este ejercicio concreto es programar, no hacer un script sencillo con selenium webdriver en python.

Comment: Entonces, empieza por ahí. Como diga la tarea en cuestión es muy fácil, aprende sobre métodos y atributos, luego podrás realizar esto.

Comment: Gracias. He intentado buscar información y tal y como es el enunciado del problema y lo que he leído sinceramente no me entero de nada. Me podrías recomendar algúna web para informarme y aprender sobre lo que me has dicho? gracias de nuevo.

Comment: Este [vídeo](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JeznW_7DlB0&t=1660s) es el mejor que encuentro en YouTube, lastimosamente está en inglés. De todos modos tiene ejemplo muy prácticos y te pueden quedar claros los conceptos.

Comment: Muchísimas gracias! espero poder ser capaz de hacerlo hoy, y, aunque sea modificar mi terrible pregunta con código para poder realizarlo correctamente. Es bastante complejo (al menos desde mi nivel irrisorio) encontrar información para leer en Español que pueda asimilar y entender. Ya si le pones la barrera idiomática...